# Spreadsheetlight Formula not working

Tags: spreadsheet, formula, spreadsheetlight

i'm using [Spreadsheetlight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/) for creating excel document. I need to use a formula on a specific cell, but it's not working. The code:

```
report.SetCellValue(string.Format("{0}{1}", Report.CELL_MAP.ACTIVITY_CRU_COL, row), string.Format("=IF({0}{1}=0; 0; ROUND(({2}{1}/{0}{1})*100; 0))", Report.CELL_MAP.ACTIVITY_REAL_MD_VAL_COL, row, Report.CELL_MAP.ACTIVITY_INVOICED_MD_VAL_COL));
```

Is there something I'm missing? Setting formulas like `'=E9'` is stored in cell as formula and works in final document. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Should it be commas instead of semicolons in the formula? Like so:

```
report.SetCellValue(string.Format("{0}{1}", Report.CELL_MAP.ACTIVITY_CRU_COL, row), string.Format("=IF({0}{1}=0, 0, ROUND(({2}{1}/{0}{1})*100, 0))", Report.CELL_MAP.ACTIVITY_REAL_MD_VAL_COL, row, Report.CELL_MAP.ACTIVITY_INVOICED_MD_VAL_COL));
```

Comment: I wanted to insert the following formula, but it doesn't work. 
Excel reports an error.
=SUMIF(D2:D13;"=EUR";E2:E13) I also tried Vincent Tan's suggestion like so: =SUMIF(D2:D13,"=EUR",E2:E13)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested Vincent's answer on SUMPRODUCT and IF formulas and I can confirm that it works.

SUMPRODUCT example:

Instead of

```
sl.SetCellValue(cellRef, "=SUMPRODUCT(A2:B2;--A1:B1=\"Something\")");
```

should be

```
sl.SetCellValue(cellRef, "=SUMPRODUCT(A2:B2,--A1:B1=\"Something\")");
```

IF example:

Instead of

```
sl.SetCellValue(cellRef, "=IF(A1=\"Something\";1;0)");
```

should be

```
sl.SetCellValue(cellRef, "=IF(A1=\"Something\",1,0)");
```